# Comparing AIC and adjusted $R^2$

Tags: r, self-study, generalized-linear-model, aic, r-squared

So, I have a homework assignment in which I'm being asked to compare the fit of two similar models by comparing their $R^2$ and AIC.  Both models were run in R, one using the `lm` command (for OLS) and the other the `glm` command; the former yielded an adjusted $R^2$ of 0.82, and the second model, with the same DV and covariates, produced an AIC of 365.96.

The only difference between the models is the "g" in the `lm`/`glm` command. The coefficients and standard errors they returned are virtually identical.

How does one compare $R^2$ and AIC? How can I tell which regression model fits the data better?

Comment: So, if coefficients and SEs are identical, what is the difference between the fits (i.e., the results not the R commands)?

Comment: Hint: think about what it means to fit a model using the GLM procedure versus the lm (OLS) procedure.

Comment: of course, the R^2 is the proportion of the variance explained by the regression line; AIC I understand as decreasing as the log-likelihood increases.  So we want a high R^2 and a low AIC. But the R^2 is bounded between 0 and 1; the AIC is only judged by how low it can get. it doesn't have an upper and lower bound such that comparisons would be easy to make.
also, i know GLM is generalized linear models; LM is linear model in R. I'm not sure how that relates to how to understand AIC and R^2, though...

Comment: Don't compare AIC and $R^2$, instead compute AIC and $R^2$ for both.

Answer (score 4):

*(I assume your homework has been turned in by now ;-).  I'll answer this so that it doesn't stay officially unanswered.)*

@user12202013 is right you don't compare an AIC to an $R^2_{\rm adj}$.  You can compare the AICs from two different models, and you can compare the $R^2_{\rm adj}$s from two different models, as ways to help you think about which model fits better.  However, I don't think that was the point of the exercise.  What you need to recognize is that linear regression (OLS) is a [special case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_case) (i.e., simplified version) of the generalized linear model.  (The topic of GLiMs is a bit involved, but to learn more about it, it may help you to read my answer here: [Difference between logit and probit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30909/7290).)  Moreover, the `R` function `glm()` fits a linear model assuming normally distributed errors by default.  In other words, I think the assignment was to notice that you got the same model using two different function calls as @Roland and @user777 hinted.