# Does higher AIC correlate with higher adjusted R squared?

Tags: r, aic

I have fitted two models.

Model 1 has 264.514 less AIC than model 2, a drop from circa 7800 to circa 7500.

However, model 2 has adjusted R^2 equal to 40 percent, while model 1 has it at 36.8 percent.

What gives? I thought such a significant $\Delta AIC$ would most likely also increase the adjusted R squared?

If it helps: model 2 and model 1 are identical, except model 1 has an exponential correlation structure with a nugget.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When AIC and Adjusted $R^2$ lead to different conclusions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140965/when-aic-and-adjusted-r2-lead-to-different-conclusions) and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83133/comparing-aic-and-adjusted-r2

Comment: @Tim- at least very similar :)

Comment: @OP AIC and $R^2$ are measuring two very different things.

Comment: Sorry-comment above got cut.  AIC and $R^2$ are measuring two very different things.  You can got a lot of information on AIC by searching 'what is AIC' on this sites search box ! Roughly, very roughly, AIC is a measure of how close your model is to the true underlying model.  Among other things AIC penalizes model complexity. $R^2$measures how well the model fits the observed data.  It tells one nothing about how well the model fits the data underlying the observations.

Comment: So AIC is a measure of how well a model will predict new data and $R^2$ merely measures how well the model fits the given data.  For example, if one adds noise variables to a model $R^2$ will improve (go up), but AIC will get worse (also go up). In particular adding noise to a model will add explanatory power to the model on the observed data, but predictions will go to hell.

Comment: "It tells one nothing about how well the model fits the data underlying the observations." $R^2 = 1$ means what?

Comment: I don't think these are exactly the same question and I think they might get different answers, so I am voting to leave both open.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question. The question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140965 has a good answer from @Carl explaining some differences but the other answers seem to catch on $R^2$ instead of $R^2_{adj}$. The question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83133 seems to have changed direction and ended up being answered with an explanation of R functions to compute OLS-models and GLM-models.

Comment: I do not know how to retract my reopen vote but the following question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197112 answered by Christoph Hank explains very well similarities and differences between $R^2_{adj}$ and AIC and you could write $R^2_{adj}$ as a function of AIC and $n$ and $k$.